# Smartgit Repositories view not showing files but folders only

Tags: git, version-control, smartgit

I used to be able to see my .js files under each folder in the Repositories section on the left hand corner of Smartgit.

But now I only see the folders, is there a setting to turn on to see the files?

[image]

Comment: SmartGit's **Repositories** view was **never** showing files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mstrap mentioned it is not possible to see files in the Repositories view/windows.

You have to look in the *Files* view/windows (screenshot *1). If it is not visible you can get it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. If the are not shown there maybe your filter settings are not correct (screenshot *2).

[image]

Comment: thanks again for responding; I confused the smartgit IDE with Webstorm, I'm not sure how that happened but I struggle from lack of sleep and memory loss; thanks again for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mac,

just make sure `View ->  Files from Subdirectories` option is checked.

[image]